# Sequence of real-rooted polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, zeroes

I've been interested in proving a log-concavity result via proving that certain family of polynomials is real-rooted. By performing a sequence of transformations, I can reduce that problem to proving that the following *very concrete* family of polynomials are real-rooted.

$$p_n(t) = p_{n-1}(t) + \frac{t}{2}  \cdot \sum_{j=2}^{n-2} \binom{n}{j}\, p_j(t)\, p_{n-j}(t).$$

With initial conditions $p_1(t)=p_2(t) = 1$. The first few values are:

$p_3(t) = 1$, $p_4(t) = 3t+1$, $p_5(t) = 13t+1$, $p_6(t) = 45t^2+38t+1$, $p_7(t) = 423t^2+94t+1$, $p_8(t) = 1575t^3+2425t^2+213t+1$.

I have tried many of the usual techniques to tackle this, without too much luck. Any suggestions are more than welcome. (It seems to be the case that the zeros of $p_n(t)$ always interlace those of $p_{n+1}(t)$, but of course I haven't been able to show it).

EDIT: The bounty would also be awarded if someone can prove the log-concavity of the coefficients of each $p_n(t)$ (independently of the real-rootedness).

Comment: For what it worth, the generating function $\sum_{n=2}^\infty p_n/n! x^n$ satisfies an ode $(f-t f^2/2)'=2x+f$.

Comment: I cannot currently provide a full answer but I believe that Lemmas 3.14 and 3.16 in Fisk's book about interlacing should be enough to prove this with a bit of effort. In particular, as you correctly point out the key might be interlacing. Once interlacing is proved a modified application of Lemma 3.16 does the job. Proving interlacing is a bit trickier, but I believe that the fact that the polynomials have all positive coefficients allows for an application of a variant of Lemma 3.14 for variable alphas. Did you try this?

Comment: @Hvjurthuk I don't see how you plan to use these two lemmas precisely (or perhaps I'm looking at the wrong version of Fisk's book). Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @FedorPetrov I think the right hand side should be $x+f$. In fact $f$ fulfills a messy transcendental equation (without derivatives of $f$), which becomes somewhat shorter if we write it in terms of $g=(tf-1)/(1+tx)$. But I doubt that it helps in any way.

Comment: Just to mark a dead end, I'll note that neither the leading coefficients or the values of $p_n(1)$ seem to appear in OEIS.

Answer (score 0):

The sequences $\{p_n\}$ or $\{p_{3n}\}$ do not seem to satisfy nice linear recursions involving derivatives (similar to how Eulerian polynomials can be shown to be real-rooted).

If you have a combinatorial interpretation for the coefficients, then
perhaps you can refine your family, so that you get more polynomials but easier recursions, and prove the interlacing property that way.

See [this page](http://symmetricfunctions.com/real-rooted.htm#polynomialRootIntro) for some references on various techniques to prove real-rootedness.

A long shot is: perhaps your polynomials are matching polynomials, (or independence set polynomials) of some graphs, and then real-rootedness follows.

Comment: Thanks Per. I do not have a combinatorial interpretation for these coefficients, but rather of a (too complicated) transformation of them. I am aware of the techniques to prove the real-rootedness for the Eulerian polynomials and other similar sequences, and I agree that those techniques do not seem to apply here. That is, in a sense, the reason I asked this question. By the way, shouldn't this "answer" be a "comment"?

Comment: @LuisFerroni Yes, sure, but its too long for a comment. In any case, a refinement would perhaps help. For example, Eulerian polynomials A_n, but where one sum over permutations where n is sent to k, (as k varies) gives a refinement which simplifies the proof of real-rootedness, see Petter Bränden's chapter on Log-concavity, realrootedness and beyond.